# C++11 vector push_back ambiguous

Tags: c++, vector, c++11

Consider the following code:

```
#include <vector>

struct S { int a; double b; };

int main()
{
    std::vector<S> v;
    v.push_back({3, 4.5});
}
```

g++ 4.4 complains that the call to push_back() is ambiguous:

```
error: call of overloaded ‘push_back(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’ is ambiguous
note: candidates are: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const _Tp&) [with _Tp = S, _Alloc = std::allocator<S>]
note:                 void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(_Tp&&) [with _Tp = S, _Alloc = std::allocator<S>]
```

Is this supposed to be ambiguous according to the Standard, or is this just an issue with g++?

I know it can be resolved by writing in the type of S explicitly:

```
v.push_back(S{3, 4.5});
```

but the type name of S may be long, so I'd rather not do that...

Comment: I'm guessing your compiler doesn't have all the new rvalue reference (move or &&) implementations completed and a rule set on which form to prefer to use for that temporary (should take the movable one since your object is a temporary)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the most recent draft (n3225), your code is in fact ambiguous. The candidates that are in vector will be

```
void push_back(const S& x);
void push_back(S&& x);
```

The question is: Is a *list-initialization* of a `const S&` a *better/worse conversion sequence* than a list-initialization of a `S&&`? Overload resolution will make both conversions *user defined conversion sequences*. This means they are *not* comparable because there is no rule that can do so.

This is handled by [core issue #1079](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1079). If that issue gets accepted, the intention is that your code calls the second candidate. Incidentally, Jason Merril is a GCC developer :)

Answer (score 6):

Does `S` have to be a POD? If not, define a constructor, and it should work.

```
struct S
{
    int a;
    double b;

public:

    S(int a, double b) : a(a), b(b) {}
};
```

Also, `v.push_back({3, 4.5})` is probably less efficient than `v.emplace_back(3, 4.5)`.

---

**Update**: Smells like a compiler bug. It works perfectly well with g++ 4.6.0 20101025 (experimental).

Comment: While useful, not really what the OP's asking? I'm also curious what happens there - why one variant is ambigous about being an lvalue/rvalue and the other's not, while they're both, well, temporaries.

Comment: @Kos: The temporaries are of different types. `{3, 4.5}` is a `std::initializer_list<double>`, whereas `S{3, 4.5}` is an `S`. Maybe it has to do with the fact that `a` is an `int` and not a `double`? Honestly, I do not know.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about emplace_back. However, it also seems to require a constructor for S.

Comment: @FredOverflow: I don't think the type of {3, 4.5} is std::initializer_list<double> - that would mean that the type of every object in the {} is coerced to be the same thing, which cannot be, since the {} syntax works for structures with widely different member types.

Comment: HighCommander4 is right, I think- from what I understood from C++0x wiki, a class needs to have a constructor like `Class(std::initializer_list<sometype> list)` to actually make use of initializer lists. This issue is about **"uniform initialization"** which is a different concept and seems to have nothing to do with std::initializer_list, I suppose - besides the brace `{}` notation.